# Why does avatar disappear upon revisiting page?

Tags: php, image, mysqli

When a user submits a picture, the file is moved to a generated folder (for security purposes) with its file pathway recorded on the database. The picture displays correctly when the user stays on the page, but when the user exits from the page and revisits it, the picture they had previously uploaded fails to  display (nothing displays at all). I seem to be unable to evoke the image from its location through its session variable and would like insight on this, thanks.

What I've tried:

1. echoing the avatar session variable -> image doesn't display at all
2. echoing the location of the image -> image displays when the user does not leave page after submitting. When the user leaves and
   revisits the page, the image does not display. In its place, a
   outline of where the image is suppose to register shows.
3. A lot of small tweaks (for instance, setting avatar session variable to location, and so on).

Here is my code:

```
     $fln = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
     if(isset($fln) && tmp_name !== "") {
       $tmp_name = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
       $fls = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
       $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
       $rdn = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
       //size checker

       if($fls > 6500000) {
          echo "Image must be less than 6.5 MB...";
       }
       else {
         mkdir("user_data/user_avatars/$rdn/");
         $location = "user_data/user_avatars/$rdn/$fln";
         move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $location);
         $imageCD = "UPDATE users SET avatar=? WHERE email=? LIMIT 1";
         $imageST = $con->prepare($imageCD);
         $imageST->bind_param('ss', $location, $_SESSION["email_login"]);
         $imageST->execute();

         $_SESSION["avatar"] = $location;
       }
           }
           else {
             $location = "/img/default_pic.jpg";

           }
```

Here is where the image is suppose to display:

```
    <img src="<?php echo  $_SESSION["avatar"]; ?>" class="profilePic" id="profilePic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The session variable will only be active as long as the user doesn't close the browser.

So if you're trying to echo `$_SESSION["avatar"]` it will work when the user just uploaded the avatar and surfs around on your page. When they leave and come back later, the session has been cleared. Furthermore, the session is only between the current user and the webserver and the avatar will only be displayed for the user itself, and not anyone else on your site!

**It will therefore not be the ideal solution to load the image from session!**

Every time a user visits your page you need to load their information from your database (including the avatar path) and display it directly from there.

Comment: This is bad news for me, because I am currently using session variables to display user information... How can I fix this using prepared statements?

Comment: You said that the avatar path gets stored in your database (Guessing MySQL database). This is where you save all your dynamic data for your page - like the path for the uploaded avatar. You then need to load the data from the database into your HTML tags every time a user visits your site. If a user for instance visits a profile page you'll probably use an ID in your URL, which you'll use to find the data in your database.

Comment: I dont know how you're using Session exactly, but Session is used to remember data across page requests, often used in login systems. When you login to StackOverflow it makes a database request to find your profile and saves data in a session about you. Every time you then surfs around StackOverflow it will look in the session and keep you logged in.

Comment: Okay, that sounds a lot more manageable than predicted. The page I am working on is a edit page, where the user can edit  his/her record on the database, so using sessions should be fine. Everything in my edit form is working except for the image display, which I don't know. Like you suggested, for the profile page where other people can view your profile, I  can just run a SELECT query and run a while loop that fetches the arrays I need and then display them into HTML tags (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Yes, so I am using the user's email as the main session reference to the database. All data the user submits is contingent on whether or not the email the user logged in with exists within the database, otherwise the user won't be able to login and enter in information.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You left out some details in your post, which made me answer the wrong question.

Comment: Do you access the session on the edit page elsewhere with success?

Comment: Yes, I have another execution within the same php block that updates the user's text records in the database with entries they edited. The entries can only be edited for that user if he/she is already logged in through the session of the email used from registration. That part is working well. So if the database, the user's personal information along with the file pathway of the profile image is stored and responsive to UPDATE queries. I just can't get the image to display everything the user goes back his/her edit page.

Comment: So regarding the avatar, the picture displays and its path is store into the database. Everything seems to work well. However, when the user leaves the edit page (to a different page) and revisits the edit page the image that they previously uploaded no longer displays at all.

Comment: Could you probably be overwriting the `$_SESSION["avatar"]` somewhere? I can't see anything wrong with the code you've provided. I would load it from the database however, to make sure you always shows the current data for the user (since you already have saved it in the database).